# How to archive user messages in ejabberd in sql database?

Tags: ejabberd

Hi we had used ejabberd 16.04 version for chat application, and i can perform user creation and sending message now what i need is i want to archive messages but i couldn't so kindly look into below code and guide me where i went wrong?

Some of the my ejabberd code:

```
auth_method: sql
default_db: sql
```

Database connection:

```
##
## MySQL server:
##
sql_type: mysql
sql_server: "127.0.0.1"
sql_database: "ejabberd"
sql_username: "root"
sql_password: "1231231213"

modules: 
   mod_mam:
     db_type: sql
```

Error log:

```
2016-07-18 12:36:49.039 [warning] <0.26092.2>@ejabberd_config:default_db:884 Module 'mod_carboncopy' doesn't support database 'sql' defined in option 'default_db', using 'mnesia' as fallback
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the output, i just added another line and got the message saved in table

```
mod_mam:
  db_type: sql
  default: always
```